# OpenCamera is configured to record in 60 FPS, however the recorded videos are in 30 FPS. Why?

Tags: camera, android-12, video-recording, google-pixel-6, frame-rate

[OpenCamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera&hl=en_US&gl=US) is configured to record in 60 FPS, however the recorded videos are in 30 FPS. Why?

I use a Pixel 6 running Android 12. I don't use slow motion video. I can record videos in 4K 60 FPS with [Google Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera&hl=en_US&gl=US).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://redd.it/xdggpo) from [rmendez011](https://www.reddit.com/user/rmendez011):

> You probably have to change Camera API to "Camera2 API", you can find this option if you press the gear icon, and scroll all the way to the bottom, press "Camera API".
>
> Not every device supports 4K 60fps recording on anything other than the stock cam.

Change Camera API to "Camera2 API" allowed me to record at 60 FPS on my Pixel 6.